# How to Pre-Generate Views for multiple DbContexts?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

We have an application which uses entity framework 4.1 with the DbContext API. The application has **multiple DbContexts** mapping to different databases and tables. This week we pre-generated the views for the DbContext with [Code first T4 templates for view generation](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/) to save on start-up time and everything was wonderful.... until we needed to use the second DbContext. At that point, we got the following exception:

> "The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'CodeFirstContainer' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views."

Whether we have generated the view for one or multiple of our DbContexts, we get that exception.

**How can I Pre-Generate Views for multiple DbContexts and still have a working application?**

I looked at the suspicious 'CodeFirstContainer' in the message to discover it was in both Pre-Generated views constructor which looked like:

```
public ViewsForBaseEntitySetsCE5A4DE7E067A5879A835C5C494F186A390ADC2D26E82631FDC17C61E7E3D076
{
    this.EdmEntityContainerName = "CodeFirstContainer";
    this.StoreEntityContainerName = "CodeFirstDatabase";
    this.HashOverMappingClosure = "198099ba4b299a8dc37402a5c4c65096d216c3ca5f3c1e6c796d33e723483d74";
    this.HashOverAllExtentViews = "85be433ad451c345f4d8e92827653fd9203be3008dd387745798f939514a0b2f";
    this.ViewCount = 14;
}
```

The only difference between both view constructor was the last 3 properties.

ALternatively, if somebody knows how I can tell EF not to use CodeFirstContainer for both DbContexts then I'd be able to change the generate views or DbContext myself and get things working... unless this is included in the hash.

Comment: I don't think it is currently possible to change edm and/or store container names.